# How do I read two strings on each line, line by line, from a file in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct, scanf

I'm trying to read lines from a file that look like:

> String1 A
>   String2 B
>   String3 C

etc..

and store them in two separate structure arrays; stringName, and group.
All I've found have been for strings separated by a symbol or other codes which are similar, but not the same issue

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <math.h>
#include "string.h"

struct StringStruct {
    char    Stringname[16];
    char    group[1];
}String[100];

int MaxNumLines = 100, i;
char str[25];

int main()
{
    // open String.dat file as a read from file
    FILE *fp1;
    errno_t string_file = fopen_s(&fp1, "String.dat", "r");

    // if String.dat not found,
    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        // print error
        printf_s("Error: String.dat not found\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    // if String.dat found
    else
    {
        // print success
        printf_s("File String.dat opened successfully\n");
    }

    // read names and assign groups
    while (fscanf_s(fp1, "%s %s", String[i].Stringname, String[i].group) != EOF)
    {
        // read names one line at a time
        for (i = 0; i < MaxNumLines; i++)
        {
            // read string name
            scanf_s(str, "%s %s", String[i].Stringname, String[i].group);
        }    

    }
    for (i = 0; i < MaxNumLines; i++)
    {
        printf_s("%-12s", String[i].Stringname);
        printf_s("%s", String[i].group);
    }
}
```

}

Now, in my eyes everything should work, but it doesn't, and I'm also getting fscanf_s warnings:

> - warning C4477: 'fscanf_s' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'unsigned int', but variadic argument 2 has type 'char *'
> - note: this argument is used as a buffer size
> - warning C4473: 'fscanf_s' : not enough arguments passed for format string
> - note: placeholders and their parameters expect 4 variadic arguments, but 2 were provided
> - note: the missing variadic argument 3 is required by format string '%s'
> - note: this argument is used by a conversion specifier

But I've looked into the fscanf_s function and everything seemingly aligns with it's description of use.

I'm not the most proficient in C, but I've been learning it over the course of the year so far, and I've been trying to find a solution to these problems for a few days, but have made no progress in that time.

Comment: Are you aware that you are using non standard variants of standard functions and that they don't work exactly the same? Read Microsoft's documentation about their safe implementations of standard functions or change to standard functions and silence the compiler.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi `_s` functions are standard C11, no? Although I'm not sure if Microsoft conforms well enough.

Comment: @DeiDei They are not standard.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi — a version of the `_s` functions are standardized in Annex K of C11, but (a) they are optional and (b) the interfaces in the standard differ in important and not easily reconciled ways from the `_s` functions implemented by Microsoft.

Comment: `while (fscanf_s(fp1, "%s %s", ...) == 2)` not `!= EOF` (otherwise you could have a *matching failure* , returning `1` (or `0`) and still consider that a good read)

Comment: Note that with `char group[1];` in the structure, you can only use `%c` and not `%s` to read the data.  The array notation is mostly superfluous, at that.

Comment: Despite my best efforts I haven't been able to resolve the '_s' function requirement, but thankfully have managed to work with them in the mean time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `scanf_s` family of functions, the format specifiers `%s`, `%c` and `%[` expect *two* arguments, not one. The first is the pointer to the buffer in which the data should be stored, and the second is the size of that buffer.

For your code, it would look something like this:

```
fscanf_s(fp1, "%s %s", String[i].Stringname, 16, String[i].group, 1)
```

Note that the regular `scanf` family of functions only take one argument (the pointer to the buffer) for these format specifies.

For can find more information on these functions [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Answer (score 0):

1. Correction suggestions: 
   1) clear requirement: scan is to scan inputs from keyboard, here you want to read strings from file, so don't use scan
   2) clear logic: in the loop of processing reading files line by line, should not use 'for' loop again. Here you'd better keep in mind, one line from the file map one struct object 
   3) good name conventions: the array name 'String' is not a good name
   4) reusable code: length of the array should be aligned with the number of lines of the file.
   5) manually cleanup: always close the file after open, free the memory after malloc.
2. If you don't need deal with the devices/hardware, it's better to study Python,which will be better to process texts. Pointers and memory of c is a little complex.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <math.h>
#include "string.h"

struct  Stringstruct
{
    char    Stringname[16];
    char    *group;
};


int MAX_LINE = 100;// max count of chars in one line

int main()
{
    // open String.dat file as a read from file
    FILE *fp1;
    errno_t string_file = fopen_s(&fp1, "String.dat", "r"); 
    char *sep = " \n";//split the string line into tokens.
    char *token = NULL;
    char *next_token = NULL;  
    char buf[100];//100 is the max chars number of one line

    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        // print error
        printf_s("Error: String.dat not found\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        // print success
        printf_s("File String.dat opened successfully\n");
    }

    //get the line count of the file, allocate memory to the array dynamically
    int linecount = 0; 
    while (fgets(buf, MAX_LINE, fp1) != NULL)
    {
        linecount++;
    }
    struct Stringstruct  *myarray = malloc(sizeof(struct Stringstruct)* linecount);

    //back to the start of the file and process the strings line by line
    rewind(fp1);

    int i = -1;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp1))//read the file line by line
    { 
        i++;
        token = strtok_s(buf, sep, &next_token); 
        int temp = strlen(token);
        strcpy_s(myarray[i].Stringname, strlen(token)+1, token); 

        //since there's newline chars at the end of the string line, like '\n' or '\r\n'
        //normally it will loop for two times, 
        //add the exception processing in this block
        while (token != NULL) 
        {
            // Get next token: 
            if (token != NULL)
            {
                //printf(" %s\n", token);
                token = strtok_s(NULL, sep, &next_token);  
                int temp = strlen(token);
                myarray[i].group = malloc(sizeof(char));
                strcpy_s(myarray[i].group, strlen(token) + 1, token); 
                break;
            }
        }

        //if the index exceed, stop the loop
        if (i >= linecount) {
            printf_s("Error: array mystring over flow\n");
            break;
        }         
    }

    fclose(fp1);//close the file

    for (i = 0; i < linecount; i++)
    {
        printf_s("%-12s", myarray[i].Stringname);
        printf_s("%s\n", myarray[i].group);
        myarray[i].group = NULL;
    }

    free(myarray);
    myarray = NULL;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Occam's razor. I'm not sure if my intention in my question was clear, but I found an incredibly simple solution to my issue:

```
for(i=0;i<num_strings;i++)
{
    fscanf_s(fp, "%16s", String[i].name, 16);
    fscanf_s(fp, "%2s", String[i].group, 2);
}
```

16 being max name length + ~2 and 2 being a comfortable size for group string.

Printing these in another for loop confirmed they work, for me at least.
Sorry if this is an obvious method for the veterans, but as I'm new to this I wasn't sure what to ask.

Thank you to those who helped!